# External library usage in eclipse

Tags: android

I want to use this library in my project:https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView I am using eclipse.I downloaded jar file and put the libs folder.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="131.50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_viewer" />
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_viewer"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting  following errors:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_color' in package 
     'com.impact.ribony'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_width' in package 
     'com.impact.ribony'
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your style if you have `border_color`, or `border_width` name in your style or dimen xml, then rename them, if it doesn't work then 
Add 
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root layout

It will be good if you use source code not jar of this Lib project

Comment: ı downloaded javadoc jar file from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccircleimageview is this correct ?

Comment: It's wrong, you have to download project add this as a lib in yr project. Then it will work

Comment: I downloaded and added as a lib in my project and compiler errors goes away.But my app is crashing with this error : Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView how can i resolve this ?

Comment: Ye goto lib project source folder copy the package then replace that in ur xml  de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

Comment: Can you explain more ? I didn't understand exactly

Comment: It is same as in the question

Comment: Navigate to CircleImageView.java location and post the package name if that class